# How to add custom class for introJS skip button?

Tags: javascript, angular, skip, intro.js

I need to hide skip button, but `.introjs-skipbutton` class is also hiding the done button(I need done button).

How to add custom class for introJS skip button?

Comment: add code sample, clarify, expected/results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below CSS fixed the issue

```
.introjs-skipbutton{
visibility: hidden !important;
}

.introjs-donebutton{
visibility: visible !important;
}
```